# Minimizing the variance of my MLE

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

> A random sample of size $n_1$ is to be drawn from a normal population
> with mean $\mu_1$ and variance $\sigma^2_1$.
>
> A second random sample of size $n_2$ is to be drawn from a normal
> population with mean $\mu_2$ and variance $\sigma^2_2$. The two samples are independent.
>
> What is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\alpha =\mu_1-\mu_2$?
>
> Assuming that the total sample size $n=n_1-n_2$ is fixed, how should
> the  observations be divided between the two populations in order to
> minimise the variance of α̂ ?

I already came up with my MLE of $\alpha =\mu_1-\mu_2$. Now I need to divide my *n* observations, provided that $n=n_1-n_2$, in such a way that I can minimize the variance of α. Any leads on how I could go about this?

Comment: That question is missing a lot of useful information

Comment: Hi Henry. Updated the question to include the problem I am working on

Comment: Noticed that it's similar with this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532709/maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-the-difference-between-two-normal-means-and-mini?answertab=oldest#tab-top). But I don't know how to proceed with the suggested answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum likelihood estimator of the difference between two normal means and minimising its variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532709/maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-the-difference-between-two-normal-means-and-mini)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\mu_1-\mu_2$ given $n_1$ and $n_2$; here this is is also the natural estimator, and is the same as the MLE of $\mu_1$ minus the MLE of $\mu_2$
- Find the variance of the MLE of $\mu_1-\mu_2$  given $n_1$ and $n_2$; it will be a function of $n_1, n_2, \sigma^2_1, \sigma^2_2$ and you can use the independence of the to parts of the MLE
- Minimise that variance of the MLE subject to $n_1+n_2=n$; probably easiest using calculus to find $n_1$ as a function of $\sigma^2_1, \sigma^2_2$ though note that $n_1$ should be an integer

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried looking for a way to minimize the variance of the MLE I got but I couldn't get an answer. Is it safe to assume that \sigma^2_1 and \sigma^2_2 are equal?

Comment: @thedarklord If they are are equal that I would have thought symmetry would suggest you want $n_1$ to be half $n$.  So you should not assume that, as the interesting question will be when they are unequal